# Derivative of integral involving differential of CDF

Tags: integration, cumulative-distribution-functions, leibniz-integral-rule

I am struggling to compute the following partial derivative of an integral

$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t} \int_{a}^{\infty} x(t) dF(x(t)) $,

where x is a random variable that depends on the deterministic variable $t$ and $F$ is the CDF of $x$.

Suppose, we could take the partial derivative inside the integral, and we could rewrite $dF(x(t)) = f(x(t))dx$, then we would have

$ \int_{a}^{\infty}  \dfrac{\partial }{\partial t} x(t) f(x(t))dx$

and apply the product rule. However, $dx(t)$ still depends on $t$. Should I further substitute the differential $dx(t)$ until I reach an expression in $dt$ ? Is this approach valid? Is there a less complicated way to compute the partial derivative?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct in thinking that the CDF of a function if defined as:
$$F[x](t)=\int_0^t x(\tau)d\tau$$
then we can say that:
$$dF[x](t)=d\left(\int_0^t x(\tau)d\tau\right)$$
so if we got back to your integral we have:
$$I=\int_a^\infty x(t)d\left(\int_0^t x(\tau)d\tau\right)$$
now if we do IBP we get:
$$I=\left[x(t)F[x](t)\right]_{t=a}^\infty-\int_a^\infty x'(t)F[x](t)$$
However I am unsure as to what this represents, I am also confused as to how you are differentiating wrt $t$ when in a way it is the integration variable. Maybe try and use LIR first and see where that gets you?

EDIT: This is not a complete answer just a suggestion too big for a comment

Comment: The cdf is defined as $ F_X(x) = P(X \leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(t)dt $. So you need to do a minor correction about the lower bound of your integral. Of course, it may end up being that the support of the random variable in question is $x \geq 0 $